# Sending large files to clients

Tags: files, dropbox, alternative

I own a new recording studio and we have been using cloud storage like Dropbox to send large files to our clients. However, I feel there must be a more practical solution that having to wait hours for the files to upload to dropbox in order for a client to download them.

I thought there might be some simple Ubuntu style OS that I could install on a junk PC. Then from that PC I'd be able to plug in a USB containing the files, place them in a folder and then share that folder to my client over the net.

Obviously security is very important as we would only want only recipient and their invited guests  to have access to that folder and no one else. The other thing that I imagine may be an issue is that of the dynamic IP address which our ISP provides. Would I need to have a static IP address for such a thing should it exist?

I'd love to know your thoughts!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) is the tool you want to look at.

Basically you run it (on *nix, by default web UI is used), access it using a browser, add a directory containing the stuff you want to share, generate a secret (to share with only the client).

On the client side, add a folder with the secret provided, it starts syncing.

Although file transfers are encrypted (Your information is never stored on a server in the cloud and your data is protected by private keys), DO encrypt you files (e.g. TrueCrypt) before you share to add an extra layer of security.